# MySQL - Trigger to update Column in another table after insert where it satisfys other values

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update, multiple-tables

First time posting, so bear with me:

I have got 3 tables: CWUsers, CWGamesList and CWOwnsGame.

CWUsers contains a users name and current loyalty points they have earned through games they have bought.

CWGamesList contains the name of the game, the console type and the loyalty points that the user will receive when purchasing game.

CWOwnsGame is a transactions table, where it records the users name, the name of the game and the console type.

Been having problems updating the CWUsers table with loyaltypoints after purchasing a game.

Originally I had a trigger after inserting into CWOwnsGame like this:

```
UPDATE CWUSERS SET loyaltyPoints = loyaltyPoints +
(SELECT loyaltyPoints FROM CWGameList WHERE gameConsole = "Wii" AND gameName = "Mario")
WHERE username = "bob"
```

Although this only works for one instance, how would you make it work for any game that is purchased.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a **`row`** trigger you have access to two versions of the row being modified: **`OLD`** contains the row as it *was* (if it existed), and **`NEW`** contains the row as it *will be* (*if* it will exist.)

To make your trigger work as you described, you would condition the **`WHERE`** clause using values from **`NEW`**, like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_loyalty_points
  AFTER INSERT ON CWUserOwnsGame
  FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE CWUsers
      SET loyaltyPoints = loyaltyPoints +
        (SELECT loyaltyPoints
          FROM CWGameList
          WHERE gameConsole = NEW.cName
            AND gameName = NEW.gName)
      WHERE username = NEW.uName;
```

I've assumed that you've named your columns consistently between tables. Note that the correct columns in **`NEW`** have the same names as the columns in `CWOwnsGame`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Hmm, getting an error when I try this. Saying "Unkown column 'gameConsole' in NEW.

Comment: That would be the appropriate column from `CWOwnsGame`. I was just guessing at the column names.

Comment: You'd guessed correctly, the column name in the table is called gameConsole

Comment: First double-check your spelling; then could you post your **`CREATE TABLE`** statements?

Comment: CREATE TABLE CWGameList(
gameConsole VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
gameName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
loyaltyPoints INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (gameName, GameConsole)
)ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE CWUsers(
userName VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
loyaltyPoints INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE CWUserOwnsGame(
 
uName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
gName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
cName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ID INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (uName) REFERENCES CWUsers (userName),

FOREIGN KEY (gName, cName) REFERENCES CWGameList (gameName, gameConsole)
)

Comment: It wasn't `NEW.gameConsole`, it was `NEW.cName`. The column names for the pseudorecord **`NEW`** have to be the same as the column names in the table the trigger is attached to.

Comment: och I must come across as an idiot :p That's it working now, thanks for all your help!